# Nested List: Count, Max, and Min

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array, nested

I have a nested list:

```
data = [[12345678, 14, 1],[135763365, 14, 0],[135763365, 12, 0],[1234, 9, 0]]
```

where I want to find the max index 1 of all the sublists.

To do this I've created this function:

```
def findBusiestPeriod ():
    result = max([item[1] for item in data])
    counter = collections.Counter(itertools.chain(*data))
    if counter[result] > 2:
       # Here's where I want to find the smallest index[0] based on 
       # the max index[1]

    return result
```

Once I have the max index `1` of the list, I want to check to see if there are duplicates (there are in the example.) If there are duplicates I want to return only the sublist with the smallest index `0`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

[`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) can do that with a key like :

#### Code:

```
sorted(data, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))[0]
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = [[12345678, 14, 1], [135763365, 14, 0],
        [135763365, 12, 0], [1234, 9, 0]]

print(sorted(data, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))[0])
```

#### Results:

```
[12345678, 14, 1]
```

Comment: Sorting is wasteful if you only want the max. `max` supports `key` as well.

Answer (score 0):

As someone already shown the `key` parameter of `sorted` function, I want to mention that the `min` and `max` functions also have a `key` parameter.

```
min(data, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
```